# How to run testNG tests using Maven POM file

Tags: maven, selenium

I have a Selenium project, using Maven and TestNG.

I have tried several different methods of getting my tests to run with a Maven command (I'm using the sure fire plugin).
When I run Maven the tests do not run.  There are no errors.

Has anyone got a good example or a tutorial that I could follow to get my test to run when I use mvn test?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the output:

```
C:\**************>mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - **************:**************:jar:1.0
[INFO]    task-segment: [test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [resources:testResources]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\**************\src\test\res
ources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [surefire:test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 02 15:14:10 BST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/38M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the surefire configuration from my POM file:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>iso-8859-1</encoding>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/main/test_suites/local/***_Test.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Are you able to run your testng xml as such?  What content do you have in the xml?  Also, I believe *** in the xml name is some actual correct value in your pom.

Comment: user64139, did you find an answer to the question? I am having the same problem, and the answer below does not solve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at this [Maven Using TestNG](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) site.

Basically all you have to do is adding a dependency to the TestNG.

```
<dependencies>
  [...]
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.3.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  [...]
</dependencies>
```

---

The default includes in `maven-surefire-plugin` are:

```
<includes>
    <include>**/Test*.java</include>
    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
    <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

That means that if the name of your test classes does not match the above include patterns then `maven-surefire-plugin` will not find them and run them.

You can change/add files to include by adding these to the plugin configuration.