# mvn test doesn't work. it only shows 'BUILD SUCCESS'

Tags: maven

I'm stuck in this problem. I'm trying to test this project with maven. I typed 'mvn test', 'mvn test-compile', 'mvn package' and so on. But it always shows same output like this:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building WorkflowProject Maven 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.177s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Sep 29 11:10:25 KST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/235M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the entire pom.xml is as follow.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>workflow.ss13</groupId>
<artifactId>WorkflowProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>WorkflowProject Maven</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>HibernateJBoss</id>
        <name>JBoss Community Repo</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven</id>
        <name>Java Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>Activiti</id>
        <url>http://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/activiti</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-alpha2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
        <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-rev-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.34</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-spring</artifactId>
        <version>5.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.168</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>WorkflowProject</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>6</source>
                    <target>6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportPlugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.5.2</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.6</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.4.3</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.9.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <configLocation>config/sun_checks.xml</configLocation>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.9</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </reportPlugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
                    <path>/WorkflowProject</path>
                    <username>tomcat</username>
                    <password>tomcat</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>               
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<issueManagement>
    <system>Redmine</system>
    <url>https://sat.inso.tuwien.ac.at/redmine/projects/qse-ase-ws12-03/issues</url>
</issueManagement>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tests may be performed by the [Surefire Maven plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) and its [`test` goal](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html).

Maven has a number of consecutive [lifecycle phases](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). One of them is the `test` phase, which would be a good phase to perform tests.

Now, goals and phases need to be bound together. You may bind them yourself, using an execution:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <id>...</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>test</phase>
       ...
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

There are also [default (built-in) lifecycle mappings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings) for common goals. Depending  on the type of project (packaging) different [default mappings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings) are applicable.

Packaging `jar` will bind `surefire:test` to the `test` phase. Packaging `pom` won't, which is why your particular expectations aren't met.

Your options here are either:

- Add an execution for the Surefire plugin
- Convert your project to another `packaging` type

If your project has Java code on board (which the reference to `maven-compiler-plugin` suggests), converting it to `packaging` `jar` may be appropriate. If you're sure this should not be a `jar` project, there is nothing wrong with defining your desired `execution`s. If you want to go very fancy, you may [introduce your own packaging type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427722/how-do-i-create-a-new-packaging-type-for-maven) with its subsequent lifecycle mappings.

Answer (score 3):

The packaging of your project is pom. If your project contains Java source code, it will not be compiled.

Change the packaging instead to jar and it will do what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I solved by changing the names of my test classes files,  default names are patterns like *Test.java, *TestCase.java, Test*.java

Take a look at this thread:[How to run testNG tests using Maven POM file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691570/how-to-run-testng-tests-using-maven-pom-file)

Answer (score 0):

all I had the same problem for a good while,

eventually, I added few changes to my "maven-surefire-plugin". So the plugin looked like that:

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <configuration> 
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.0</version>
           <configuration>
                <includes>  
                  <include>**/*LoginRunner.java</include>
                </includes>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
          </configuration> 
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
```

The change was mades with the syrfire plugin - I added

tags to specify the TestRunner class

Hope that helps (both plugins are needed to run maven correctly)